# Viewmodel methods calling 4 times when page opening xamarin froms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvm, viewmodel

When I navgite to this DepoAktarımBarkodPage methods in viewmodel calling 4 times. It makes 4  times api call and this makes problem for us.

```
 public class DepoAktarımBarkodPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{   public DepoAktarımBarkodPageViewModel()
    {
        AddBarkodToMyList = new Command<string>(addBarkod);
        //BarkodgetirCommand = new Command(barkodGetir);
        StokPopUpOpenCommand = new Command(stokPopUpOpen);
        EvrakLineDeleteCommand = new Command(satirSil);
        ChangeTempMiktarCommand = new Command<string>(changeMyTempMiktar);
        ScannerOpenCommand = new Command(scannerOpen);
        GetResultCommand = new Command(async (r) => await GetScannedAsync(r));
        SelectTempBarkod = new Command<string>(SelectMyTempBarkod);
        SelectGRaf = new Command<string>(changeTempGRaf);
        SelectCRaf = new Command<string>(changeTempCRaf);
        OzetListeDoldur = new Command(OzetPageListDoldur);
        SerbestMikOpenCommand = new Command(serbestMikPopUpOpen);

       GetDepoDetayForStokHareket();
        changeMyTempMiktar("");
        fillRafLists();
        detectYeniStok();
        Console.WriteLine($"belge no : {belgeNO}");
       

    }}
```

This is output:

```
 belge no : 
 belge no : 
 belge no : 
 belge no :
```

These methods calling 4 times when I open this page.
What could have caused this?

Comment: the only way the constructor is called multiple times is if you are creating multiple instances.  You have not posted any code demonstrating how/where you create the VM

Comment: When I initialize vm like this DepoAktarımBarkodPageViewModel viewModel = new DepoAktarımBarkodPageViewModel(); is it again calling ? @jason

Comment: Where are you doing this construction, in which method?

Comment: 1) Do you have any XAML, anywhere in app, that looks something like `<...BindingContext> <...:DepoAktarımBarkodPageViewModel>`? Do you do `new DepoAktarımBarkodPageViewModel();` anywhere else in the app? **Add to question** a list of all places in which either of these are done. (Not just on that page.) 2) For c# code, put **breakpoint** on each `new DepoAktarımBarkodPageViewModel();`, to find out which ones are called when. For XAML, consider REMOVING from XAML, instead doing in page's (or view's) constructor: `BindingContext = new DepoAktarımBarkodPageViewModel();` So you can breakpoint.

Comment: Thanks for your answers! @ToolmakerSteve I check these initializions and then make project work without them and now my problem fixed.